# Pass Html Page from View to Controller in MVC5 through a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public byte[] GetPDF(string pHTML) { 
byte[] bPDF = null;   
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);  
// 1: create object of a itextsharp document class 
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);  
// 2: we create a itextsharp pdfwriter that listens to the document and directs a XML-stream to a file 
PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);   
// 3: we create a worker parse the document     
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);   
// 4: we open document and start the worker on the document    
doc.Open();     
htmlWorker.StartDocument(); 
// 5: parse the html into the document     
htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);      
// 6: close the document and the worker     
htmlWorker.EndDocument();     
htmlWorker.Close();     
doc.Close();      
bPDF = ms.ToArray();      
return bPDF; }
```

How do I pass HTML page from view to controller in MVC5 through a string?

In this following code how do I get the string pHTML?

Comment: You want to upload a file?

Comment: I want to generate a pdf report from a HTML page. I want to pass HTML code from Razor View to controller, where  GetPDF() is a method of Controller and it's parameter  pHTML is hold the html page.

Comment: You can upload HTML file and do whatever you want. Essentially HTML is also a file.